# code included in function doesn't perform return

Tags: php

I use filters in a PHP function, these filters can return an error, however, the return in the include doesn't seem to work:

ie: I have the following 'include.php' file:

```
return 'test';
```

In my main code I do this:

```
echo retval();
function retval(){
   include 'include.php';
   return 'why';
}
```

I expect this code to echo 'test', but it echoes 'why'.

This is the bare problem. In production the 'include.php' is a filter. It sets variables, which works in a function. If 'include.php' is:

```
$a = 'test';
```

and my main function is:

```
echo retval();
function retval(){
    include 'include.php';
    return $a;
}
```

I get the expected code 'test'.

If I return from the 'include.php' file like this:

```
return 'test';
$a = 'test';
```

I get "undefined variable: a in main.php", I expect $a not being set if it comes after a return (in 'include.php'), what I don't expect is that 'return $a' in 'main.php' is still executed when 'include.php' did a return already.

If you put the result of 'include.php' in a variable it will hold the returned value if there is a return in the 'include.php'. It will be an 'int(1)' when there is no value returned. I could test for this, but is there a better way of doing this? Why am I seeing these unexpected results?

Comment: how about `return include 'include.php';` ?

Comment: Include.php only returns when it figured no more executing needs to be done. In all other cases it needs to do more processing with the main code. I could test for include.php returning a value, but if it returns the integer 1 I can’t say if that’s the actual return value or the default include is returning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [manual](https://php.net/include) this is expected behaviour: included files always have a return value (`FALSE` versus `1`) by default, which can be overwritten by using `return` yourself.

Mind the scopes: the `return` of the included file (no matter if implicit or explicit) does not become the `return` of where it is included in (i.e. your function). While the inclusion is in most parts a substitution exceptions apply (one of them is: the included file must start with `<?php` again instead of automatically being assumed PHP already; the other is that `return` only addresses the file (inclusion), not the outcome).

Addressing your other problem (distinguishing between PHP's default return of `1` versus one induced by yourself) should be done thru convention: either never have such a return value yourself, or always set a variable/constant.